# error when trying to load logon info for crystal reports during runtime

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, crystal-reports

I'm using following method which resides in a class to load logon info to crystal reports during runtime (VB.Net, SQL Server, Crystal Reports). Database resides in an another PC of my LAN. This works properly on my development environment and original database server. (dbUsername, dbPwd, serverName, dbName are variables)

```
Public Shared Sub Impersonate(ByVal myRpt As ReportDocument)
    ' Set the login info dynamically for the report
    Dim username As String = (dbUsername)
    Dim password As String = (dbPwd)
    Dim Server As String = (serverName)
    Dim Database As String = (dbName)
    Dim logonInfo As New TableLogOnInfo

    Dim table As Table

    For Each table In myRpt.Database.Tables
        logonInfo = table.LogOnInfo
        logonInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = Server
        logonInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = Database
        logonInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = username
        logonInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = password
        table.ApplyLogOnInfo(logonInfo)
        table.Location = Database & ".dbo." & table.Name
    Next table
End Sub
```

I use the above method when loading reports as follows.

```
Dim crepDailSalSum As New repDailySaleSummary      ' Declaring a new crystal report
CReportAuthentication.Impersonate(crepDailSalSum)  ' Loading the logon info
```

Later, I have setup a new database server and allowed the remote connection and made the necessary settings to allow TCP/IP connections. Now, all the other functions of the programme is working except reports. I get the following error when i try to view or print a report.

[image]

I can't figure out what's wrong, and I feel the code is correct since it's working in the original development environment. Is it a permission issue at the Database server side?. Any advice will be highly appreciated.

I use the following connection string which is inside of a module. (I do not use a DSN).

```
Public connString As String = "Data Source=SQLSERVER\SLMA;Database=POS_DB;User Id=sa;Password =xxxxxxxx;" 'global connection string
```

Comment: Is the working `serverName` actually a System DSN configured on your machine? You may need to create a new System DSN for the new server.

Comment: i do not use a system DSN. I use a connection string which is in a module of my project.

Answer (score 0):

After some testing, I found out that there is nothing wrong with the code. Problem was at the database server port. It can be resolved as follows,

Go to

- Sql Server Configuration Manager
- Sql Server Network Configuration
- Protocols
- TCP/IP properties
- IP Addresses Tab
- IP All
- Change the TCP port to 1433 under IP All

Even though the connection string works for other functions, It is necessary to set the port at the database server as above in-order to get the crystal reports working.